# Internal Resistances of Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, dc, internal-resistance

I have read somewhere on a forum that there are two effective internal resistances of a capacitor in a DC circuit but can't seem to find any further information. From what I read 'parallel resistance' exists for a capacitor and is typically in the order of megaohms. Is this information correct, and if so can anyone point me to a more reliable source which contains some more background on the theory of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The ideal capacitor has no resistance either in series or in parallel with it.  What you are therefore asking about is non-ideal behavior.

Truly modeling all the non-ideal characteristics of any real part is impossible.  Everything has some series inductance, some series resistance, some leakage resistance, and some parasitic capacitance.  Then the extra resistances, capacitances, and inductances of the model each have their own non-ideal characteristics.  This mess blows up exponentially, and has to be carried out a infinite number of levels to get to reality.

So what you are really asking is whether there are two resistances *in some simplified model* of a non-ideal capacitor.  There certainly can be, depeding on what you consider simple versus useful enough.

If you start out saying you only want to model the non-ideal characteristics of a capacitor with two resistances, then the obvious choice for those would be the *equivalent series resistance* (ESR), and the leakage resistance.

The ESR can be a few mΩ or even less (eventually the equivalent series inductance dominates) for small ceramic caps, up to a few Ohms for small electrolytic caps.

The leakage resistance accounts for the reality that the insulation used to make the capacitor isn't perfect.  Even glass or other ceramics will allow a little charge to trickle thru with applied voltage.  This is the reason that caps self-discharge.  Air-plate capacitors come about as close as possible to no leakage (very high effective leakage resistance).  However, something has to eventually hold the plates in place, so there is always some leakage path thru solid material.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. There is no perfect insulator, just more or less perfect. This is why capacitors have leakage (equivalent to a resistor in parallel with the capacitor).

How much leakage depends on the dielectric material of the capacitor.

Comment: Might be helpful to note that this resistance is usually called "Equivalent Series Resistance" aka ESR.

Comment: @MIL-SPEC:  The cause of ESR and leakage are not the same.  Leakage can be equated to a resistor in parallel with the capacitor.  ESR can be equated to a resistor in series with the capacitor - hence the name "equivalent **series** resistance."  Long Pham was describing the leakage,  not the ESR.

Comment: @JRE you're right, I skimmed

Answer (score 0):

I think an ideal capacitor has a high resistance in parallel (across the leads) which would make the leakage after it's charged negligible.  It would also have a low resistance in series, so that if you connect it to a battery it would charge fast, with minimal internal resistance limiting the current.  First answer is wrong with respect to parallel resistance.